# Get all Products with an API request in BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I want to get a list of all the products from my BigCommerce store using an API call. This is the code I have used:

```
fetch("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/##########/v3/catalog/products", {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "no-cors",
  "X-Auth-Token": "###############################",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Accept: "application/json",
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

I have used the correct store hash and access token but I get this error:

[image: error]

I understand this is a very basic question but I would like some help as I am stuck.

Using the rest client extension and the same credentials, I am able to get the list of products:

[image: rest client extension]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing the headers object as well as missing quotes around Accept. Also, if you're running this on the client side, this will not work, as you 'd need make a server side API request to get all products. To do so, you will need to make the API request to some middleware application.

In addition to making the request on the server side, try modifying it a bit to look like this:

```
fetch(`url`,{
      method: 'GET',  
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': '<token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': `application/json`
      }
    })  
.then((res) => res.json())  
.then((json) => console.log(json));
```